# How to filter a multidimensional array of objects based on Role?

Tags: php

I use the MenuFactory object to dynamically create navbar items. I have these objects:

```
class MenuFactory
{
    
    public static build(): Menu
    {
        $menu[] = new MenuItem("Home", "/home", ["HOST", "USER", "ADMIN"]);
        $menu[] = new MenuItem("About", "/about", ["HOST", "USER", "ADMIN"]);
        $menu[] = new MenuItem("Contact", "/contact", ["HOST", "USER", "ADMIN"]);
        $menu[] = new DropDownItem("Dropdown item", [
            new MenuItem("Sub-item 1", "/sub-item1", ["USER", "ADMIN"]),
            new MenuItem("Sub-item 2", "/sub-item2", ["USER"])
        ]);
        $menu[] = new MenuItem("Item", "/item", ["HOST"]);
        return new Menu($menu);
    }
}
```

> class Menu:

```
class Menu
{
    public const ROLE_HOST = "HOST";
    public const ROLE_USER = "USER";
    public const ROLE_ADMIN = "ADMIN";


    /**
     *@param array<MenuItem>
     */
    public function __construct(
        private array $menuItems,
        private array $role = [self::ROLE_HOST]
    ){}

    public function build()
    {
        $result = "<ul class=\"nav-menu\">%s</ul>";
        $items = array_map(fn ($item) => $item->build(), $this->menuItems);
        return sprintf($result, implode("", $items));
    }

    public function setRole(...$role): self
    {
        $this->role = $role;
        return $this;
    }

    private function filterByRole(string ...$role): self
    {
        // Here I am trying to filter items based on role.
        $filtered = [];
        foreach ($this->menuItems as $item) {
            if ($item instanceof MenuItem) {
                if (in_array($item->getRole(), $role)) {
                    $filtered[] = $item;
                }
            }

            if ($item instanceof DropDownItem) {
                $item->filterItemsByRole(...$role);
            }
        }
        $this->menuItems = $filtered;
        return $this;
    }
```

> class MenuItem

```
class MenuItem 
{
    public function __construct(
        private string $title,
        private string $anchor,
        private ?array $role = [Menu::ROLE_HOST]
    ){}

    public function build(): string
    {
        return sprintf(
            "<li><a href=\"%s\">%s</a></li>",
            $this->anchor,
            $this->title
        );
     }

     public function getRole(): array
     {
         return $this->role;
     }

     public function setTitle(string $value)
     {
         $this->title = $value;
     }

     public function setAnchor(string $value)
     {
         $this->anchor = $value;
     }
}
```

> class DropDownItem

```
class DropDownItem
{
    public function __construct(
        private string $title,
    
        /**
         * @param array<MenuItem> $menuItems
         */
         private array $menuItems,
         private ?array $role = [Menu::ROLE_HOST]
    ){}

    public function getItems(): array
    {
        return $this->menuItems;
    }

    public function getRole(): array
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    public function setRole(string ...$role): void
    {
        $this->role = $role;
    }

    public function build(): string
    {
        $result = <<<HTM
            <li class="menu-has-children">
                <a href="">%s</a>
                <ul>
                    %s
                </ul>
        HTM;
        $items = array_map(fn($item) => $item->build(), $this->menuItems);
        return sprintf(
            $result,
            $this->title, 
            implode("", $items)
        );
    }

    public function filterItemsByRole(string ...$role): self
    {
        // Here I am trying to filter items based on role.
        $filtered = array_filter(
            $this->menuItems,
            fn($item) => in_array($item->getRole(), $role)
        );
        $this->menuItems = $filtered;
        return $this;
     }
```

> File: index.php

```
$menu = MenuFactory::build();
echo $menu->filterByRole(['ADMIN', 'USER'])->build();
```

Here I want to build a Menu based on the role "ADMIN" and "USER", but it is not happening. I've been dealing with it pretty much all day today. Maybe I'm just tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Menu::filterByRole you are checking if array is in array for example let's take the first one MenuItem `getRole() will return ["HOST", "USER", "ADMIN"]` so you basically checking `if(in_array(["HOST", "USER", "ADMIN"], $role)` which will always lead to false, you have to check if those 2 arrays have at least one common element, also consider of renaming your methods, they are misleading, after reading your code i will assume getRole will return string instead of array

```
if (in_array($item->getRole(), $role)) { // getRole reuturn array, $role is also an array
    $filtered[] = $item;
}
```

i also found 2 more problems

1. you are trying to call private method from menu
2. you are passing array to filterByRole but first of all you need to unpack it with `...`

Comment: Thanks! I also realized today that the MenuItem::getRole() method returns an array. It was fatigue. @Boorsuk